# Server for virtualization

Tags: virtualization, hp, hp-proliant, nic

**HP Proliant DL380 G5**

I have looked at this server for some good virtualization. I can get the server for around 450usd 2x xenon (X5355) 2 x 72GB HDD 8GB Ram
As my g3 360 and g4 360 and g3 360 are starting to get a bit slow.

I will be running exsi 4.1 or 5? Not that many vms, but a litle bit. Just for a test environment not anything else.
Is that a good way to go or is there any other types in that price range (ebay) to recommend?
Sorry for my English, i'm from norway :)

Kind regards

Comment: Shopping questions, even from Norway, are off topic here and other SE sites.

Answer (score 1):

The [HP ProLiant DL380 G5](http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/12477_na/12477_na.html) server series works well and is fully supported for VMWare use (with ESXi 4.1 and 5/5.1). This comes from experience running the system in production *and* its place on the [VMWare hardware compatibility list (HCL)](http://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/search.php).

The only downside to using this particular platform for virtualization is its limited RAM expandability (8 slots) and the high cost of its RAM.

Comment: WE HAVE THE SAME HARDWARE AND WE DONT HAVE ANY PROBLEM. BUT THEY SHOULD ENABLE __VT ENABLE__ ONLY WANT HE GOOGLE:  how to enable Virtualization Technology (VT) in MOTHERBOARD BIOS?